# Circular View Path exception

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to create a simple user creation program using angular and spring boot. In the user creation part i am getting exception : Circular view path [createUser]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/createUser] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.).

I have seen multiple answers in stack overflow related to the same issue but I am unable to resolve this.

Attached is the code:

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/createUser",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void createUser(@RequestBody String user) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    User userObj=mapper.readValue(user, User.class);
    UserFunction uf = new UserFunction();
    uf.createUser(userObj);
}
```

Webpage:

```
    <body>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <form ng-submit="createUser()" name="myForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.id" value="user.id">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.name" value="user.name">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Age</td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="user.age" value="user.age">
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit">
        <h2>Id: {{user.id}}</h2>
    <h2>Name: {{user.name}}</h2>
    <h2>Age: {{user.age}}</h2>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);
    app.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.user = {
            name : "",
            id : 0,
            age : 0
        };
        $scope.createUser = function() {
            var data=JSON.stringify($scope.user);

            $http.post("/createUser", data).then(function() {
                alert("User created");
            }, function() {

            })
        }
    })
</script>
```

From the answers to this issue in forum I understand I have to make some changes in configuration but where to make those changes. I am unable to understand.
Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you expect the create user request to end up after `uf.createUser (...)` processes?

Comment: I want user to redirect to a User.html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved after I changed my controller function to:

```
   @RequestMapping(value="/createUser",method=RequestMethod.POST,consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity createUser(@RequestBody String user) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
    User userObj=mapper.readValue(user, User.class);
    UserFunction uf = new UserFunction();
    uf.createUser(userObj);
     return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your view resolver doesn't know where to actually redirect the control once `createUser` method executed. As like @Jayant said, try to add `@ResponseBody` in `createUser` method so that view resolver wont look for redirection page, instead it will send the response as it is to the place of invocation.